# Accessing a certain range of matrix elements in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix in which I want to zero certain specific elements.

For instance, imagine that my matrix is:

```
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)
```

I then have two vectors indicating which elements to keep

```
m.from <- c(2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
m.to   <- c(7, 9, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 8)
```

So, for instance I will keep elements 3:6 in row 1, and set element 1:2 and 7:10 to 0.
For line 2 I will keep 6:8 and zero the rest, and so on.

Now, I could easily do:

```
for (line in 1:nrow(m))
    {
    m[line, 1:m.from[line]] <- 0
    m[line, m.to[line]:ncol(m)] <- 0
    }
```

which gives the correct result.

In my specific case, however, I am operating on a ~15000 x 3000 matrix which makes using this kind of loop excruciatingly long.

How can I speed up this code? I though of using `apply`, but how do I access the correct index of m.from and m.to?

Comment: I haven't thought it through completely, but I wonder if a fast solution could be had by attaching `m.from` and `m.to` as additional columns to your matrix. Then an `apply` solution would be trivial, and you might even be able to vectorize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple matrix oriented solution:

```
m[col(m) <= m.from] <- 0
m[col(m) >= m.to] <- 0
m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0   21   31   41   51    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0   52   62   72    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0   43    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0   44   54   64    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   65   75    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0   36    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0   17   27   37   47    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0   48   58   68    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0   29    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0   60   70    0    0     0
```

(I think I might win the R Golf prize on this one , too.) For which my entry would be:

```
m[col(m)<=m.from|col(m)>= m.to]<-0
```

Comment: Double bogey!! Try `z=col(m);m[z<=m.from|z>=m.to]=0`. I encourage R enthusiasts to give this a try: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions. R has potential for short answers, but is not always well voted.

Comment: Joke aside about the code golf, your answer to the question is VERY elegant. You got my vote.

Comment: You can actually do that? Wow, I was not expecting all of these variants.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution will be one that pre-calculates all of the indices to be replaced, and then replaces them with a single assignment operation.

Since R stores matrices in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), I find it easier to think about sequences of elements to be replaced in a transposed version of your matrix. That's what I've used below. If, however, the two calls to `t()` are too costly, I'm sure you can figure out a clever way to calculate the indices of the untransposed matrix -- perhaps using a two column matrix containing row and column indices.

```
## Your example
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)
m.from <- c(2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
m.to   <- c(7, 9, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 8)

## Let's work with a transposed version of your matrix
tm <- t(m)

## Calculate indices of cells to be replaced
i <- (seq_len(ncol(tm)) - 1) * nrow(tm)
m.to   <- c(1, m.to + i)
m.from <- c(m.from + i, length(m))
ii <- unlist(mapply(seq, from = m.to, to = m.from))

## Perform replacement and transpose back results
tm[ii] <- 0
m <- t(tm)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    0    0   21   31   41   51    0    0    0     0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0   52   62   72    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0   43    0    0    0    0     0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    0   44   54   64    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   65   75    0     0
#  [6,]    0    0    0   36    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [7,]    0   17   27   37   47    0    0    0    0     0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0   48   58   68    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    0   29    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0   60   70    0    0     0
```

Comment: This looks very interesting indeed... I am going to try it and I will let you know!

Comment: Beautiful! It is extremely fast even with a big matrix!

Answer (score 2):

A `sapply` version.

```
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)
m.from <- c(2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
m.to   <- c(7, 9, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 8)

t(sapply(1:nrow(m), function(i) replace(m[i,], c(1:m.from[i], m.to[i]:ncol(m)), 0 )))   



     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0   21   31   41   51    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0   52   62   72    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0   43    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0   44   54   64    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   65   75    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0   36    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0   17   27   37   47    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0   48   58   68    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0   29    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0   60   70    0    0     0
```

Elapsed time not tested yet

Comment: Nice one! This is even faster than the other solution.

Comment: Very interesting. Good to know that sapply is so well optimized for this sort of thing.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: I guess the problem in the previous solution is that you have `m`, its transposed and `ii` and with a big matrix that takes up a lot of memory.

Comment: @nico -- Yep, transposition can take a long time. Since Jilber's solution still requires one call to `t()`, I've supplied a second answer that requires no transpositions. I'll be very interested to know whether it provides any further speedup...

Comment: @Josh O'Brien: I do not have the data here at home, I will try tomorrow at work and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This option constructs a two-column matrix indexing elements to be replaced, and requires no matrix transpositions, so *should* be hard to beat, speedwise

```
## Your data
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)
m.from <- c(2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
m.to   <- c(7, 9, 6, 8, 9, 5, 6, 8, 4, 8)

## Construct a two column matrix with row (ii) and column (jj) indices
## of cells to be replaced
ii <- rep.int(1:ncol(m), times = (m.from + (ncol(m) - m.to + 1)))
jj <- mapply(seq, from = m.from + 1, to = m.to - 1)
jj <- unlist(sapply(jj, function(X) setdiff(1:10,X)))
ij <- cbind(ii, jj)

## Replace cells
m[ij] <- 0
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    0    0   21   31   41   51    0    0    0     0
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    0   52   62   72    0     0
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0   43    0    0    0    0     0
#  [4,]    0    0    0    0   44   54   64    0    0     0
#  [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   65   75    0     0
#  [6,]    0    0    0   36    0    0    0    0    0     0
#  [7,]    0   17   27   37   47    0    0    0    0     0
#  [8,]    0    0    0    0   48   58   68    0    0     0
#  [9,]    0    0   29    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0   60   70    0    0     0
```